# Opening a port to a VM on Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, wso2

Firstly, apologies if similar questions have been answered before, but the Azure configuration seems to have changes since most of the posts I have seen so far.

I have an application which I have installed on an Azure VM [Windows server 2012].
It's actually wso2 API manager, if anybody has experience of that.

The application fires up Tomcat and listens for SSL traffic on port 9443. Why it's not 443 I'm not sure.

I've set up an Inbound Security rule on my Network Security Group, as follows:

Priority : 1010
Source: Any
Service: Custom
Protocol: Any
Port Range: 9443
Action : Allow

I still have no joy accessing this from a browser though, I get the slightly confusing "This site can't be reached / the connection was reset" error.

I'd welcome any pointers to get this working or to debug!

Comment: Have you also added an exception to the Windows firewall..?

Comment: yeah, windows firewall would be the only reason this doesn't work, also check if tomcat does indeed listen on that port

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced nearly the same issue that you did.  What worked for me:

1) I added my inbound rule prior to any other inbound rule.  I noticed your rule is 1010 which means it's being applied after the default RDP rule is.  No, this shouldn't make a difference, but it may.

2) When you create your inbound rule, hit the "advanced" button, choose the CIDR option and route the traffic to the internal IP address of the VM.

3) For the destination port range I chose only the port I needed.  In your case 9443.

The issue for me was the internal IP address.  Once I set that everything started working for me.